# Structure on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

How much structure do I need to endow a smooth manifold, $M$ with in order to be able to talk about addition and scalar multiplication on a point $p\in M$?

EDIT (In response to the comments):  For example, you can't talk about speed at a point $p\in M$ until there is a metric defined on the manifold.  Also, if $M=R^n$ then it is clear that addition and multiplication at point is well defined.  However, my question is, what is the minimum amount of structure I can add to a general smooth manifold $M$ in order for $\sum_i c_ip_i$ where $c_i\in \mathbb{R}$ to be well defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "how much structure" ? please explain

Comment: What do you mean by "addition and scalar multiplication on a point $p\in M$?

Comment: I edited the question in response to these comments.

Comment: Isn't any such thing just a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "well defined"?

Comment: Yes, a vector space would do the trick and a vector space is a manifold.  But, is that the most general manifold structure we can give $M$?

Comment: @CanisLupus:  By well defined I meant $\sum_i c_ip_i$ takes you to another point in the manifold.

Comment: well.. you probably also want multiplication to be associative and stuff like that.  In that case you're going to get just vector spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make more demands on what you want $\sum_ic_ip_i$ to mean.  You can take formal sums, so that no two are equivalent, but that's boring.  You could ask that the operations of addition and scalar multiplication be maps to the manifold ( ie. $\sum_i c_i p_i \in M$ ).  This is a little more interesting.  Especially if you ask that the functions $\mu_c(p)=cp$ and $\nu(p,q)=p+q$ are smooth.  You get things like circles and vector spaces.  Also, check out the wiki page for Lie Groups, for something more general.

There are other important groups on points though.  For example, if you take formal sums of points modulo certain relations, you get things like Homology Groups, Chow Groups, etc.

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, or if you're sure.

Comment: That pretty much nailed it.  Thanks.  Sorry for not being more clear.